# How to get image data from a file input in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, imagepicker

I want to get the data from an input file in react. I have created a class with the data as a state. The idea is that the data should be updated every time the input changes. As this happens, an image should load with the input data.

The code below is what I have created, but it does not work.

```
class ImagePicker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: null
        }
    }

    handleDataChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            data: e.target.value
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <input type='file' onChange={this.handleDataChange} />
                <img src={this.state.data}></img>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't know what the problem is, could you help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

```
handleDataChange = event => {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    this.setState({
      data: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Also use `URL.revokeObjectURL()` to release the previous one, otherwise it will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem:

```
class ImagePicker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        file: null
      }
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({
        file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
      })
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <img src={this.state.file}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

When picking a file you pick a Url to that file. You can turn this url into a png file by using URL.createObjectURL().

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).